# if elif then statment bash script not working as expected

Tags: bash

I'm quite new to programming. I'm trying to create a script which I'll run on 3 servers. This script should get the hostname and then run the appropriate command. I guess I should have use 'cases' although I'm not sure how. 
Here's my code below.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Get hostname
hostname="$HOSTNAME"

PATH_DEV="some_path"
PATH_PREPROD="some_path"
PATH_PROD="some_path"

if [ $hostname == "dev" ];
then 

    find $PATH_DEV -name '*.mysql.gz' -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf '{}' \;

elif [ $hostname == "prod" ];

then 

    find $PATH_PROD -name '*.mysql.gz' -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf '{}' \;

elif [ $hostname == "preprod" ];

then

    find $PATH_PREPROD -name '*.mysql.gz' -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf '{}' \;

else 

echo "Unknown hostname!";

fi
```

It's only will run on "dev". For the other 2 cases, it'll return "Unknown hostname!" 
What I'm doing wrong? :(

Thanks.

Comment: Your code seems ok. Are you sure it doesn't exeute the elif part for the other 2 cases? Did you check that by printing `$hostname` before the if-fi block that it is `"prod"` and `"preprod"`? I suspect $hostname doesn't contain `prod` or `preprod`, hence it fails for those 2 cases.

Comment: Try executing this script as bash -x scriptname

Comment: what happens if you do echo $HOSTNAME on prod or preprod?

Comment: Ermm ... this is quite stupid :| ... I've followed your suggestions and did echo $HOSTNAME and guess what ... it returns fqdn. All 3 systems run Centos. Although running simple "hostname" on both "prod" and "preprod" it returns short names. Thanks!

Comment: Also, have a habit of quoting strings.. `if [ $hostname == "dev" ];` -> `if [ "$hostname" == "dev" ];` to save against empty strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your main question has already been kinda answered in the comments. But as you mentioned that you probably better use `case`, here is the thing: Your assumption is correct, you definitely should use a `case` statement instead of the `if`-`elif`-construct. One of the advantages will be that matching the host name against patterns will will also solve the problem of fully qualified host names for you. Here is my solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH_DEV="some_path"
PATH_PREPROD="some_path"
PATH_PROD="some_path"

case "$HOSTNAME" in
  dev|dev.*)
    PATH_TO_USE="$PATH_DEV"
    ;;
  prod|prod.*)
    PATH_TO_USE="$PATH_PROD"
    ;;
  preprod|preprod.*)
    PATH_TO_USE="$PATH_PREPROD"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Unknown hostname: $HOSTNAME"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
find "$PATH_TO_USE" -name '*.mysql.gz' -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

The case statement evaluates the value in $HOSTNAME and checks if it is "dev" or starts with "dev.", if it is "prod" or starts with "prod.", if it is "devprod" or starts with "devprod." respectively. When a match is made, the variable PATH_TO_USE is set to the value of the corresponding PATH_XXX variable. If no specific match is found, the match-always-pattern `*)` will match and the script terminates with an error message (note that the error message contains the not-matching host name. This safes a lot of work sometimes ;-) ).

If all goes well, the find command is executed at the end. (Another note: try to avoid duplication wherever you can. Doing *one* find command at the end allows you to change its other parameters in one place.).

Comment: The pattern in each case is a file matching pattern, not a regular expression. `.` matches a literal `.` character. Unless that's what you're actually looking for, you want `dev|dev*)`, not `dev|dev.*)`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Well, from the comments, you can see that the pattern I propose works for the use case. It matches both simple host names and fully qualified host names. (The dot in there is the DNS separator, not a wildcard.) And I believe I even explained how the pattern matches both. I started with a simpler pattern `dev*)`, but that pattern had the disadvantage that it also matched "device" which might a completely different host, so I decided to use the explicit `dev|dev.*)`. How do you think I should improve the answer? Is it really worth mentioning that the patterns are not regexps?

Comment: I'd use `dev?(.*))`. No, people should know that patterns aren't regex. I would add that all-caps variable names are strongly discouraged. I also prefer not to use redundant quoting, such as on case statements and assignments. The recursive rm is pointless because of the `-type f`. With GNU find you could also use `-delete`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot guys. I have changed the script and used cases and it works perfectly and it also look much better :)